# Xamarin. Duda con conceptos básicos de funcionamiento

Tags: .net, xamarin

Desconozco el funcionamiento del entorno de programación de Xamarin para dispositivos móviles pero me llama poderosamente la atención lo que leo en su página web: comentan que las aplicaciones son compiladas para mayor rendimiento.

¿Cómo funciona? Es decir, el lenguaje que utiliza, C#, es compilado a código intermedio y precisa el .Net framework para ejecutarse. ¿Se puede compilar a código nativo independientemente del procesador que tenga el móvil?

Si es realmente compilable a código máquina y además permite que el mismo código se pueda ejecutar en Android e iOS, ¿cómo es que no se impone como plataforma de desarrollo para dispositivos móviles?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Cuando creas el proyecto. De hecho, Xamarin crea dos carpetas raíces. Uno para cada sistema operativo(Android, IOS). El problema es cuando la App se vuelve complicada. Aparentemente Xamarin aun no puedo abarcar todo.